# How to pass a value from a popup form to a PHP page using JQuery & Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

It appears my question has been asked a couple of times before, yet I still can't seem to get my code to work - even though I believe I use the very same code as the solutions to those questions.

So I am using the [SimpleModal JQuery plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to create a form in a popup window. This window contains the following HTML:

```
<div id="containerInfo" class='modalPopUp' style='display:none'>
        <form id="frmContainerInfo" method="post" action="index.php">
            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">
                <h1>Test popup/h1>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class='cargoInfoForm'>
                    <label class='cifLabel'>Location:</label>
                    <select id="ddlLoc" name="ddlLoc" class="cifDDL" style="width: 130">
                        <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                        <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
                        <option value="Hongkong">Hongkong</option>
                        <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <label class='cifLabel'>Date:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="locDatePicker" name="locDatePicker" value="" class="cifInputField" style="width: 130">
                    <br/>
                    <button id="saveLocInfo" name="buttonSubmitInfo" type="submit" class="cifSaveButton">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Then I try to send the results of this form to my PHP page upon pressing the Save button in the popup window, so I can retrieve the value of the two fields (ddLock and locDatePicker). To do this I attempt to use JQuery and Ajax, which looks like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
             $(".editDisplay-button").click(function(){
                $("#containerInfo").modal();
                }); 

            $("#saveLocInfo").on("click", function(){
            var locval  = $("#ddlLoc").val();
            var dateval    = $("#locDatePicker").val();
            var locvalLen    = locval.length;

            if(locvalLen < 4) {
                    $("#locval").addClass("error");
            }

            if(locvalLen >= 4) {
        // if location lettercount is four or bigger
        $("#saveLocInfo").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'container.php',
                data: $("#frmContainerInfo").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                                var $response=$(data);
                                alert($response.filter('#ddlLoc').text());   
                            }
                    });


                    }
                });
            }); 

    </script>
```

It appears the data I retrieve doesn't contain any values, because my alert doesn't show the location field value. Which I find odd considering I am mimicking working code of other people that had this problem. After this JQuery/Ajax code I try to access the values in my PHP file (though I believe I never retrieved the values to begin with), which looks like this:

```
<?php
     $location = $_POST['ddlLoc'];
     $dateFieldValue = $_POST['locDatePicker'];

     echo ($location);
     echo ($dateFieldValue);
?>
```

How can I get this to work, or alternatively, how can I retrieve the values of the input fields of my popup window's form in my PHP file?

Thanks!

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap.

Comment: Have you tried using local storage or cookie to store ddLock and locDatePicker to retrieve it later?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're trying to retrive the value from the `$_POST` array using a key that is NOT the `name` of the inputs.

*You're using the ID.* Wrong!

```
<?php
     $location = $_POST['ddlLock']; // "ddLock" is the ID in the HTML. Well, neither that because there's a "k" letter.
     $dateFieldValue = $_POST['locDatePicker']; // "locDatePicker" is the ID in the HTML

     echo ($location);
     echo ($dateFieldValue);
?>
```

Your input text

```
<input type="text" id="locDatePicker" value="" class="cifInputField" style="width: 130">
```

doesn't even have any `name` attribute. Change it to this:

```
<input type="text" id="locDatePicker" name="locDatePicker" value="" class="cifInputField" style="width: 130">
```

Same thing for the `<select>`. That's yours: See? name and ID are different and you're calling the ID in your PHP code.

```
<select id="ddlLoc" name="ddlLocOptions" class="cifDDL" style="width: 130">
    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
    <option value="Hongkong">Hongkong</option>
    <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>
```

Change it to this:

```
<select id="ddlLoc" name="ddlLoc" class="cifDDL" style="width: 130">
    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
    <option value="Hongkong">Hongkong</option>
    <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>
```

And change your PHP code so it will work

```
<?php
     $location = $_POST['ddlLoc']; // "ddLoc" is now the NAME attr
     $dateFieldValue = $_POST['locDatePicker']; // "locDatePicker" is now the NAME attr

     echo ($location);
     echo ($dateFieldValue);
?>
```

***IMPORTANT***: Be careful! You wrote 'ddlLoc **k** ' in the PHP, but the name should be 'ddlLoc' i guess ( k letter is needless )

Comment: I've been so tunnelvisioned on the Jquery part that I did not check my HTML naming. I corrected this and used the naming you suggested. I still don't retrieve the two values unfortunately. Shouldn't the                      alert($response.filter('#ddlLoc').text()); part already show the name of location? Because it does not. I feel like I am not retrieving any data in the JQuery. Thanks for the naming heads up though!

Comment: @Kheran, well, that's the problem. You missed the names. `ddlLoc` should be the name of the `<select>` and the key name in the `$_POST`, while `locDatePicker` is the name of the `<input>` and the key name. It's as simple as that. Unfortunately I cannot check your code from here. Try maybe to debug the `$_POST` array with `var_dump`. Check also what outputs your `$("#frmContainerInfo").serialize()`

Comment: I've adjusted my original post according to what I'm running now (based on your first response). I believe the names are now set correctly, but I still can't retrieve the values from data as an alert in the JQuery code. And thus I am not retrieving the values in PHP either (even with the naming corrected). Appreciate your help so far though, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Kheran NP. Try to retrive each value doing `$('body').find('#locDatePicker').val()` and tell me if this gets the value to you

Comment: Yes this does get the two values using your code to retrieve them.

Comment: @Kheran: Good! Then the plugin dynamicaly removes and re-creates the elements. `serialize()` should work though. Well, for now, just try to replace it with something like `{ locDatePicker: $('body').find('#locDatePicker').val(), ddlLoc: $('body').find('#ddlLoc').val() }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53947/discussion-between-kevin-cittadini-and-kheran)